# Debug remotely with PyCharm a Flask application running on Apache

Tags: python, apache, debugging, pycharm, mod-wsgi

I'm on the following scenario:

- Programming a Flask application locally in PyCharm.
- Remote Deploy on a server using Apache (wsgi_mod)
- Access to the server via SSH

On the server I get a segmentation fault that locally doesn't happen to me (Dockerization in progress...) and I would need to debug from my computer what happens on the server.

I found this [PyCharm link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html) but I'm not able to make it work. I don't know if it's because in these conditions you can't or I'm doing it wrong.

Locally my application runs in `localhost:<LOCAL_PORT>` and in the server the configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName <URL>

        WSGIDaemonProcess <PROCESS_NAME> user=<USER> group=<GROUP> threads=<N> python-path=<PYTHON_PATH>
        WSGIScriptAlias / <REMOTE_PROJECT_FOLDER>/<SCRIPT>.wsgi

        <Directory <REMOTE_PROJECT_FOLDER>>
                WSGIProcessGroup <PROCESS_NAME>
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                WSGIScriptReloading On
                Require all granted
                </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there any way that, without major server-side modifications, I can debug that application? I don't understand if the following should be added locally, remotely or in both places:

```
import pydevd_pycharm

pydevd_pycharm.settrace('172.20.208.95', port=12345, stdoutToServer=True,
                        stderrToServer=True)
```

And I'm not sure which IP / port (local? Remote?) to use for debug either.

I know that Docker is the solution for these cases but it is not currently implemented.

Comment: did you ever figure this out ? i have my pycharm and apache on the same machine. i am unable to debug my script when its running with apache

Comment: Not actually :/. I decided to abadon this problem since almost everything is service-oriented right now, so my next task is to debug the application running inside a container.

Comment: I was able to do it via pydev because  pycharm-community does not allow remote debugging